# Finding the probability mass function given the cumulative distribution function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose that the cumulative distribution function of a random variable X is given by

$
F(a) = 
\begin{cases} 
    0,& a < 0 \\
    1/5, & 0 \leq a < 2 \\
    2/5, & 2 \leq a < 4 \\
    1, & a \geq 4 
\end{cases}
$

Find the probability mass function of X?

My reasoning is as follows:
The cdf is discontinuous at the points 0, 2, and 4. Between these $F'(a)$ is defined and $=0$, hence the pmf needs definition only at these points. But how do we get the probabilities at a = 0, 2, 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P(X\leq0)=\frac15$ and from $P(X\leq a)=0$ for each $a<0$ it follows that $P(X<0)=0$.

Then $$P(X=0)=P(X\leq0)-P(X<0)=\frac15-0=\frac15$$

The others (at $2$ and $4$) can be found likewise.

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

$$F'(4)=F(a>4)-F(2\le a<4)$$
$$F'(2)=F(2\le a<4)-F(0\le a<2)$$
$$F'(0)=F(0\le a<2)-F(a<0)$$

Comment: You are right, but I didn't understand why?

Comment: Cumulative distribution function $F(a)$ is the sum of the probabilities from $x=0$ to $x=a$. So the pmf $F'(a)$ is obtained by taking the respective differences for the points where the function is discontinuous....Is it clear??

Comment: What is the meaning of e.g. $F(a>4)$ where $F$ is a function? Yes, I understand what you mean, but is this an acknowledged notation for that?

Comment: @drhab I don't know for sure. I used for proper understanding only. Better notation would have been $F(a)\big|_{a>4}$.

Comment: I think it just means $P[a>4]$