# pmf from cdf at fractional points

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, discrete-mathematics

I am new to probability and am taking an introductory probability course this semester. We have a cdf as:

$\begin{align}F(x) = 
 0    \space &\text{ if }       x <1, \\
\frac14   \space &\text{ if } 1\le   x <\frac53, \\
 \frac13   \space &\text{ if } \frac53\le x <2, \\
 \frac35   \space &\text{ if } 2\le   x <\frac52, \\
1    \space &\text{ if }       x \ge\frac52.\end{align}$

I calculated $P(X=1) = F(1\le x< \frac53) - F(X<1) = 1/4$

and $P(X=2) = F(2\le x<5/2) - F(5/3\le x<2) = \frac{4}{15}$

My question is do I need to find the pmfs at $5/3(P(X=\frac53)) \space \text{and }  5/2(P(X=\frac52))$ also?

At [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1518909/finding-the-probability-mass-function-given-the-cumulative-distribution-function) a comment by SchrodingersCat mentions we "taking the respective differences for the points where the function is discontinuous". So I am curious if we should do the same at non-integer points too?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guide:

- Yes, you need to do that at the place where the function is discontinuous. The probability would be the magnitude of the jump.
- Being integer is just a coincidence. It is possible for a pmf to not take positive value at any integer value at all.
- Also remember to state that for the remaining points without jump, the corresponding probability would  be $0$.
- After you compute your pmf, do a sanity check that the sum of the probability adds up to $1$.